# JQuery Mobile ListView

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I'm having 2 strange problems with the code I'm using to pull in some data to use in a listview. Here is my javascript:

```
function getOrders(status, url) {
    $(function () {
        //check if url from pagination
        if (!url) {
            url = api_url + '/orders/?callback=?&status=' + status;
        } else {
            url = root_url + url + '&callback=?';
        }
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        $.getJSON(url, null, function (d) {
            //declare a variable with which to build our output (it's best to buffer output and only do one append at the end since DOM manipulation is CPU expensive)
            var output = '';

            //iterate through the data (we could also get rid of the jQuery here by using `for (key in data) {
            $.each(d.objects, function (index, value) {

                output += '<li><a id="' + value.reference + '" href="view_order.html" class="view_order"><h3>' + value.reference + ' - ' + value.client.company + '</h3><p>' + value.order_date + ' ' + value.user.username + '</p></a><a href="asd" data-icon="gear"  data-iconpos="notext"></a></li>';
            });
            $('#orders_list').html(output).listview('refresh');
            //if paginated, update next button
            if (d.meta.next) {
                $("#id_ordersNext").attr('href', d.meta.next);
                $("#id_ordersNext").show();
            } else {
                $("#id_ordersNext").hide();
            }
            if (d.meta.previous) {
                $("#id_ordersPrevious").attr('href', d.meta.previous);
                $("#id_ordersPrevious").show();
            } else {
                $("#id_ordersPrevious").hide();
            }
            $("#id_ordersTotal").html(d.meta.total_count);
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        });
    });
}

$(function () {

    //bind the nav
    $(".order_nav").die();
    $(".order_nav").live('click', function () {
        $(".order_nav").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-active');
        });
        $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
        getOrders($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });

    //bind the view order
    $(".view_order").die();
    $(".view_order").live('click', function () {
        //save var
        window.viewOrderReference = $(this).attr('id');
        $.mobile.changePage("view_order.html");
    });

    $("#id_ordersNext,#id_ordersPrevious").die();
    $("#id_ordersNext,#id_ordersPrevious").live('click', function () {
        getOrders(null, $(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });

    //default view
    getOrders('Order Placed');
});
```

Here is the html I'm using for the page that's being loaded via JQMobile:

```
<div data-role="page" data-needs-auth='true'>
    <script src="js/list_orders.js"></script>
    <div class="headerDiv" data-role='header' data-theme='b'><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a>

        <h1>Jubilee Distributors</h1>
        <a href="login.html" class="logged_in" data-icon="home">Login</a></div>
    <div data-role='navbar'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Order Placed" class='ui-btn-active order_nav' data-ajax="false">Placed</a></li>
            <li><a href="Order Picked" class='order_nav' data-ajax="false">Picked</a></li>
            <li><a href="Order Delivered" class='order_nav' data-ajax="false">Delivered</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role='listview' id="orders_list" data-filter="true"><li>No records found</li></ul>
        <p><a href='#' id='id_ordersPrevious' style='display:none;' data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Previous</a> <span id='id_ordersTotal' class='record-count'></span> records found <a href='#' id='id_ordersNext' style='display:none;' data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Previous</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id='footerDiv' data-role="footer"></div>
</div>
```

This all works fine in any browser on a desktop, but when I run it on an Android device 2 things happen, or rather don't.

1. The last line in the $(function() - getOrders('Order Placed'), doesn't seem to execute, or if it does, it's not updating the list with the returned result. If I click the first link with the "Orders Placed" it works no probs.
2. The addClass is not actually adding the class.

Like I said, this all works fine in any desktop browser, but not on the Android device.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Fixed the second problem, however the first problem still exists.. It works if I navigate to the page, then away from it, then back again tho.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this error by changing the dom ready function to pageinit.